# How to decrypt all rows from mysql db

Tags: mysql, sql, aes

Hopefully not an already answered question, but I want to be able to select everything while decrypting it similar to just doing `select * from` like below:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT AES_DECRYPT(*, UNHEX('...");
$sql->execute(array("test2", "test2"));
```

But this doesn't seem to work, creates a syntax error. Is there any other way?

Comment: Why is everything AES encrypted? That provides zero security if your key is like right there in the query.

Comment: How could I keep my keys secure? If you could link me to anything, or any searches I should do, that would be nice.

Comment: What keys? What attacks are you trying to prevent? How serious are the compromise risks?

Comment: I was reffering to the string I used for the encryption and decryption. I don't really know what I'm trying to prevent. Just wanna make sure that if someone gets into my database they won't be able to read it easily, I'm probably over doing it, but yeah.

Comment: You're just making your own life difficult. If your application code can read the data then the attacker doesn't care if the rows are encrypted or not, they'll just pull it through your application. Encryption at rest for backups is important, it means you won't lose control of backups or be vulnerable to someone imaging your database server, but that's a whole other strategy. This seems completely pointless.

Comment: Encrypted data means you can't index anything at all, you can't filter or search, your data is basically opaque garbage. Systems designed like this are extremely limited in what they can do. Focus on securing your database properly, then lock down your application server as tightly as you can.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'm a very big noob at this, and probably get screwed some day, but hopefully I'll learn from it.

Comment: If you're using PHP the #1 thing you should look out for is SQL injection. #2 is XSS. Focus on those threats first. Encryption of this sort is usually reserved for exceptional, very special situations, and the key must be kept separate from the data and application server, like it may be held by the client and the client alone.

Comment: For php, I've started using pdo statements, would `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`  be the solution for xss?

Comment: PDO with prepared statements and placeholder values is fine, but you can do better than that by using an ORM. For XSS that's one way to do it, but another is to use a proper template system instead of just banging out raw PHP views. These have escaping methods baked in.

Comment: So are the other ways more secure? (for xss) Or would using `htmlspecialchars` be good enough?

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is the bare minimum. Look at how a framework like [Laravel handles templates](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade) especially with how data is introduced using placeholders, not just raw PHP jammed in randomly. The risk with `htmlspecialchars` is you'll get lazy or forget. A template system like that makes it easy because it's done by default and you have to do extra work to *not* do it.

Comment: I'll probably stick with htmlspecialchars, because I would have to alter a lot of my existing code for the templates _laziness_ however I'll defintely look into it in the future, or with newer features I plan on adding soon for my website, as it looks a lot more professional and organized.

Comment: @TedBed interesting (ignore comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to be able to select everything while decrypting it similar to just doing `select * from`

You can't do that. [`AES_DECRYPT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt), and sister function `AES_ENCRYPT()`, operates on strings, not on records.

You do need to repeat the function call for each and every column you want to decrypt:

```
select
    aes_decrypt(col1, ...) as decrypted_col1,
    aes_decrypt(col2, ...) as decrypted_col2,
    ...
from mytable
```

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll have to work a little bit more now, but at least I know.